# Tkinter не видит буфер обмена ПК после сборки в .exe

Tags: python, tkinter, auto-py-to-exe, буферизация

Есть программа с текстовыми полями, но вставить\выделить ничего не получается после запаковки в .exe файл.
Написал кнопки которые вставляют из буфера обмена в окно для текста, через запуск в IDE работает, а в .exe нет. Побывал запускать от имени администратора - тоже не помогает. Иногда все же удается вставить из буфера. В чем может быть проблема? Код прикрепил на всякий случай.

```
import tkinter
import pyperclip

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title('Price Changer')


def copy_output():
   textbox.delete("1.0", 'end')
   textbox2.delete("1.0", 'end')

def paste_input():
   pasta = pyperclip.paste()
   textbox.insert("1.0", pasta)

clear_but = tkinter.Button(text="clear", background='green', command=copy_output)
paste_but = tkinter.Button(text="paste", background='orange', command=paste_input)

textbox = tkinter.Text()

clear_but.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='e')
paste_but.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w')
textbox.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Дополню, сразу после конвертации в .exe он работает, но если перезапустить комп или положить в архив и достать оттуда - не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Собрал в .exe с помощью cx_Freeze и теперь проблем не наблюдается.